# Javascript: Object function definition

Tags: javascript

I stumbled about something strange today and can not find any information about this behavior ...

So, in general you can do something like this.

```
var test = {
    wtf: function() {
        console.log("Yep");
    }
}

test.wtf(); // shows "Yep"
```

But because of some typo I accidentally ended up with following and now I'm wondering why this is working. Can anyone explain this to me?

```
var test = {
  wtf() {
    console.log("Why?");
  }
};

test.wtf(); // shows "Why?"
```

Comment: That's valid ES6 syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [Method Definition syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) introduced in ES6. This is currently supported in up-to-date versions of Chrome, Firefox and Opera.

> ### Method Definitions
>
> Starting with ECMAScript 2015 (ES6), a shorter syntax for method definitions on objects initializers is introduced. It is a shorthand for a function assigned to the method's name.
>
> #### Description
>
> The shorthand syntax is similar to the getter and setter syntax introduced in ECMAScript 5.
>
> Given the following code:
>
> ```
> var obj = {
>   foo: function() {},
>   bar: function() {}
> };
> ```
>
> You are now able to shorten this to:
>
> ```
> var obj = {
>    foo() {},
>    bar() {}
>  };
> ```
>
> — [MDN's documentation on Method Definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)

Answer (score 2):

That's valid ES6 syntax. It is a shorthand called "method definition".

For more information, visit http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/03/es6-and-method-definitions.html. The spec is [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-method-definitions).

Answer (score -1):

This happens because you are working in a ECMASCRIPT-6 Environment,

Actually Javascript is changing, you can follow progresses at: 
https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

by the way:
In ECMASCRIPT-5 you can only define a member in this way:

```
var myObject = {
  someMethod: function() {}
};
```

ECMASCRIPT-6 introduces some "shorthands", syntactic-sugar.

```
var myObject = {
  someMethod() {}
};
```

further info are available at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Comment: Your first example is broken. It's invalid syntactically. Anyway, a complete answer should give the name of this construct and references.

Comment: it was just a mistake, `=` instead of `:`. 
Reference aws listed at the end.
Thanks for the feedback!